# UIButton addTarget:action:forControlEvents: not working using itself as a target?

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a subclass of `UIButton`, is it possible to add a target for the button using the button itself? For example

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: ya just changes one think that is [YOURBUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(METHODNAME:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: I want to add a target inner of the class button, instead of the button's superview. I add a target for the button in its superview (as your said), it worked.

Comment: when do you call addTarget? on init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working bcoz you are adding self as target. You need to add Your ViewController as target on which you button is added.

```
[self addTarget:viewController action:@selector(onClick:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: We can not add button itself as a target. It always require its superview to become the target for which button is going to perform the action..

Comment: Your answer and my test results are the same, although do not know the reason, but certainly can not use self, and the target must be uiview or its subclasses, and the uiview must also be the superview of the button, if there is relevant reference Information is even more grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply change this:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

To this:

```
[MyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Thx, i knew where was my problem, your answer was not my expected answer. Why [self addTarget:self action:...... is illegal?